# State is updated and logged properly but value in HTML is still wrong

Tags: reactjs, state, react-hooks

I update the state with the useEffect hooks and I can see in the logs afterwards that the state had been updated.

When I then return the components view, the value return inside the html is still the old state.

I logged the state right after i set it in the useEffect hook + i even logged it in the return statement right before i return the HTML element with the state value and both show me that the state was updated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
[...]

interface CalculatedTotals {
    beforeTax: number;
    afterTax: number;
}

const InvoiceView = (props: Invoice) => {
    const { recipient, dueDate, id, createdAt, items } = props;

    const [itemsTotal, setItemsTotal] = useState<CalculatedTotals[]>([]);

    const [invoiceTotal, setInvoiceTotal] = useState<CalculatedTotals>({
        beforeTax: 0,
        afterTax: 0
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const calculateItems = () => {
            const newItemsTotal: CalculatedTotals[] = [];
            items.forEach(item => {
                const itemsTotalBeforeTax = item.qty * item.unitPriceNet;
                const unitPriceWithTaxes = item.unitPriceNet + item.taxRate;
                const itemsTotalAfterTax = item.qty * unitPriceWithTaxes;
                const newItemTotal = {
                    beforeTax: itemsTotalBeforeTax,
                    afterTax: itemsTotalAfterTax
                };

                newItemsTotal.push(newItemTotal);
            });

            setItemsTotal(newItemsTotal);

        };

        calculateItems();

        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const calculateInvoice = () => {
            let newTotal: CalculatedTotals = { beforeTax: 0, afterTax: 0 };

            itemsTotal.forEach(itemTotal => {
                newTotal = invoiceTotal;
                newTotal.beforeTax += itemTotal.beforeTax;
                newTotal.afterTax += itemTotal.afterTax;
            });

            setInvoiceTotal(newTotal);
                        console.log(invoiceTotal); // logged correctly updated state. now e.g { beforeTax: 12, afterTax: 14 }
        };

        calculateInvoice();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [itemsTotal]);

    return (
        <ViewInvoicePaper>
            [...]
                <Grid
                    container={true}
                    item={true}
                    xs={12}
                    sm={12}
                    md={12}
                    direction="column"
                    justify="center"
                    alignItems="flex-end"
                >
                    <span data-testid="invoiceTotalBeforeTax">
                        {console.log(invoiceTotal) // returns the actual upadted values, lets say beforeTax: 12, afterTax: 14}
                        {`Total Before Tax : ${invoiceTotal.beforeTax}` // but here it still returns 0}
                    </span>
                    <span data-testid="invoiceTotalAfterTax" >
                        {invoiceTotal.afterTax // same here}
                    </span>
                </Grid>
                <Grid />
            </Grid>
        </ViewInvoicePaper>
    );
};

export default InvoiceView;
```

I expect the values not to be `0` but instead be the sum of all items total amount. 
[That is how it looks in the browser](https://ibb.co/2hZmBkd)

Comment: Can you create a codepen to reproduce it?

Comment: Can you explain why you are using `useEffect` here? It is needed for performing side effects. You are probably don't even need any state. From your code it looks like you can calculate all needed data based on the props inside the method without any hooks and states.

Comment: I have a hard time reproducing it to be honest. One thing I noted and am curious tho is that when i remove the dependency of the second use effect hook that it feels as if both `useEffects` run concurrently and not in order synchronously. This question matters to me because on the first render `itemTotals` should be set and derived from it in the second `useEffect` hook should the `invoiceTotals be set` but the state on the first render does not change because it shows me that `itemTotals` is still `[]` as if the first effect has not finished running yet

Comment: @chumakoff good question, you are right! ha

Comment: Obviously without the need of state and useEffect i don't run into this problem. Yet, I am really curious if someone is able to tell me what was happening here,